# jQuery: Check if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

i have an html page where i have multiple "checkboxes" each of them are call a function onclick.

Something like this

```
onclick="manage(val1, val2)
```

And in my function when i am getting the check status of checkbox, giving false every time.

```
function manage(val1, val2) {
    **if ($(this).is(":checked")) {** //returns false everytime
        //do something
        //
    }
    else {
        //do something
    }
}
```

please tell me where i am doing mistake...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `manage(val1, val2)` is called, `this` will be the global object (or undefined if you're in strict mode)

But you can set the `this` value manually with `call`.  Try this:

```
onclick="manage.call(this, val1, val2);"
```

Now `this` will be whatever you just clicked on.

Just to clarify a bit more, inside the `onclick="____"` `this` is the thinig you clicked on.  But once you call functions from there, this becomes the global object in the functions.  So:

```
onclick="foo(this);"

function foo(val) {
    alert(this);
    alert(val);
}
```

Alerts `[object DomWindow]` (the global object) then `[object HtmlInputElement]` (the thing I clicked on)

Without getting into too much detail, this is a result of how "function invocation" works in JavaScript.

Comment: I could have sworn browsers did that automatically...  Edit:  Or maybe I'm thinking about when things are done like onclick="blah(this)"  :)

Comment: +1 for using `call` instead of just passing as a regular argument. Brings it into conformity with the expectation.

Comment: @ЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖ - :) (thanks to your username I never have to worry about having too short of a comment)

Comment: @ЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖ - and yeah, call and apply are some of my favorite tools to use in JavaScript

Comment: @AdamRackis: Finally someone who sees the glass half full! Though I'll be changing it shortly for the sake of the complainers. ;)

Comment: ...and I agree. I don't know what I'd do without `call` and `apply`.

Comment: @ЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖ - I always just copy paste the first few letters and let auto complete do the rest.  So, out of curiosity, is there an ascii value I can use to get that first character.  Does that name mean something in another language?  So many questions!!!

Comment: @AdamRackis: The name is meaningless. Just obnoxious noise. And there are unicode character mappings, though I'd have to find them again.

Comment: That is quite a beast of a name.  And I think that call and apply are quite integral to the design of JavaScript :p.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){  // append click to any checkbox
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Just some suggestions, there is the `:checkbox` selector and `this.checked`. Your selector can take advantage of QSA without any pre-processing though :)

Comment: @alex: `[type="checkbox"]` is `qSA` friendly, unless I misunderstood you?

Comment: @amnotiam: I think you misunderstood me :)

Comment: @alex: Ah yes, very likely. I thought you were saying `[type="checkbox"]` would prevent `qSA`. Totally with you on using `this.checked` though. :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set the context of your onclick, or pass it 'this' as a parameter:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="manage(this, 'val1', 'val2');"></input>
<script>
function manage(that, val1, val2) {
   if ($(that).is(":checked")) {
       alert('checked')
    }
    else {
       alert('unchecked')
    }
}
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6SBa/1/)

Of course your best bet is to NOT use in-line javascript, go with something like TerryR wrote.